# Prove that $(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{b+c}{2}, \frac{a+c}{2})=(a,b,c)$ for odd and positive $a, b, c$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> For odd positive integers $a, b$ and $c$, show that $$(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{b+c}{2}, \frac{a+c}{2})=(a,b,c)$$

**My attempt to this problem** is the following:

Let $n$ be the greatest common divisor of $a, b$ and $c$. We then have
$$\begin{cases} a=nx\\ b=ny\\ c=nz \end{cases}$$
where one of $x, y$ and $z$ is coprime to any of the remaining two variables.
Thus we must have one of $x+y, y+z, x+z$ being coprime to any of the remaining two expressions, meaning that their $(x+y, y+z, x+z)=1$.

And since $x, y$ and $z$ are odd, it must be true that $x+y, y+z,$ $x+z$ are even. As such, they must always be whole numbers which are divisible by $n$.

$$(\frac{n(x+y)}{2},\frac{n(y+z)}{2},\frac{n(x+z)}{2})=(nx,ny,nz)$$

Since the division on the LHS does not change how $n$ divides the terms, we thus have $n$ as the GCD on both sides.

I'm quite new to proofs, so any feedback for improvements or critical mistakes that I have made is much appreciated!

Comment: You almost did it. Use rule $GCD(nx,ny,nz)=n GCD(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes things clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show two things.

- For any $d$ which divides $a,b$ and $c$, it is also true $d$ divides $(a+b)/2,(a+c)/2,$ and $(b+c)/2$. 
  *Hint*: To do this, consider how  $(a+b)/2$ relates to the factors of $a$ and $b$.
- For any $d$ which divides $(a+b)/2, (a+c)/2$, and $(b+c)/2$, it also divides $a,b$ and $c$. 
   *Hint:* To do this, show how $a$ can be written as a simple linear combination of the three averages.

Comment: I think I am able to get your first bullet point. For the second point, I am not quite sure what you mean. I obtained $a=d(x+y−z)$ with $\frac{a+b}{2}=dx,\frac{a+c}{2}=dy,\frac{b+c}{2}=dz$, showing that $d|a$. However, in the event that $z$ is larger than $x+y$, would this still hold? Was this the intended result? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Your equation proves that $d$ divides $a$, so you are done! You are concerned that $x+y-z$ could be negative. However, since $a$ and $d$ are positive, the equation $a=d(x+y-z)$ proves this cannot happen. Basically, your correct arithmetic up to this point proves that $z$ is less than $x+y$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right, I understand now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Let $n$ be the greatest common divisor of $a, b$ and $c$. We then have
> $$\begin{cases} a=nx\\ b=ny\\ c=nz \end{cases}$$ where one of $x, y$
> and $z$ is coprime to any of the remaining two variables.

False. You have $a=3, b=5, c=15$. In that case, $n=1$, but none of $x,y,z$ is coprime to any of the rremaining two variables. $3$ is not coprime with $15$, $5$ is not coprime to $15$, and $15$ is not coprime to any of them.

Furthermore, you first say in your proof that $(x+y, y+z, x+z)$ are coprime, and then later on, you say that all three numbers are divisible by $2$. This is contradictory, if they are all divisible by $2$, then their greatest common divisor must also be divisible by $2$, so it cannot be $1$, and they cannot be coprime.

Comment: 'False. You have a=3,b=5,c=15.', I agree with you. What I meant to write was that since $a$ is still coprime to $b$ (3 coprime to 5), then that would mean $(a, b, c)=1$. Would it be more accurate if I instead stated that "where one of $x,y$ and $z$ is coprime to at least one of the remaining two variables."?

For the second point, I completely agree with you, and would like to apologise for the silly mistake. Sorry for this stupid question I am about to ask, but they will indeed follow the revised statement (except with $x+y, y+z, x+z$) above after they are divided by 2, right?

Comment: Would it be more accurate if I instead stated that "where one of x,y and z is coprime to at least one of the remaining two variables."

Nope, the counterexample there would be $6, 15, 10$. The three numbers are coprime, i.e. their GCD is $1$. But each number has one prime factor in common with each of the other numbers. You can find many such triples, just take $p_1, p_2, p_3$ as three primes, and then $p_1\cdot p_2,p_2\cdot p_3$ and $p_3\cdot p_1$ are an example.